# Convert values from a string column into a numerical column

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.6

I have a table, coming from Excel, with 21K rows, which is partially filled with numbers, and partially with the `""` value from excel, which is displayed as `<Null>` in the table view.

I need to use the number values to display as graduated colors, which ArgMap won't allow me, as they are stored in a string column.

I tried converting those values into Double()'s using the field calculator as is mentioned in this article from ESRI: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002287

The code I used from the article is:

```
Dim String, Check
String = [String field name]
Check = IsNumeric(String)
If Check = True then
Output = CDbl(String)
else
Output = null
End if
```

And wrote `Output` in the second field.

Where I clicked on the appropriate field name to insert the name behind String.

This however produces a column full of `<NULL>` values, without any error message.

Comment: What format is your data in now / how did you import the table from Excel? Can you add the code you used in Field Calculator?

Comment: I just clicked the add data button, and selected my excel file. It is of Type: String, and uses a `,` as decimal seperator.

Comment: Then you are trying to edit the excel file from ArcMap. I dont Think you should do that. After you add the table, right click it and export to a file geodatabase. Then try your code on the exported table. What is your next step after you manage to calculate the field?

Comment: Yep, this did the trick. Perhaps you want to add that as an answer @BERA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just added the excel file to the map, you are trying to edit it using ArcMap which you should avoid.

Right-click the added table and export to a file geodatabase and try your code again on the file geodatabase table.

(btw you should try and learn python instead of vb in Field Calculator, vb is going away)

Comment: I'm also used to program in VBA, so vb is really close to that. Shame to see it go :(